# How to extend the length of Tcolorbox in Beamer

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox, geometry

I'm using the following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} %math
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
%--------------------
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
colback=bg,
colframe=blue!75!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
coltitle=blue!75!black,
colbacktitle=bg,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-1.2mm, xshift=2mm},
title=#2,
#1}

\usepackage{color} %couleur

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{mybox}
[colframe=blue!75!black,coltitle=black!75!black,colbacktitle=white!90!blue, 
]{\ding{43} Definition}
Let ${\bf T} = (T_1,\cdots, T_d)$ be $d$-tuple of operators in $\mathcal{B}
 (\mathcal{H}).$ The joint numerical range of ${\bf T}$ is the set $JtW({\bf 
 T})$ of  $\mathbb{C}^d$  such
 that
 $$JtW({\bf T})=\{(\langle T_1 x\; |\;x\rangle,\langle T_1 x\; 
 |\;x\rangle,\cdots,\langle T_d x
  |\;x\rangle)\;:x \in \mathcal{H},\;\;\|x\|=1\}.$$
\end{mybox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

I want to extend the length of the block. Could you please help me?

Comment: Help you and help us finding the issue. Please include the rest of the code to make it compilable.

Comment: if i add standard preamble to you code sniped, i can't reproduce your image. without complete small document is not possible to help you.

Comment: You have too many `\;` which add extra spaces within the formula. They are not really necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because your formula is too long and does not respect the margins, so I recommend splitting it in two lines. However, you can achieve the effect you want by adding the `oversize` option to `mybox`.

[image: oversize tcolorbox]

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%-----
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} %math
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
%--------------------
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
colback=bg,
colframe=blue!75!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
coltitle=blue!75!black,
colbacktitle=bg,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-1.2mm, xshift=2mm},
title=#2,
#1}

\usepackage{color} %couleur

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{mybox}
        [oversize, colframe=blue!75!black,coltitle=black!75!black,colbacktitle=white!90!blue, 
        ]{\ding{43} Definition}
        Let ${\bf T} = (T_1,\cdots, T_d)$ be $d$-tuple of operators in $\mathcal{B}
        (\mathcal{H}).$ The joint numerical range of ${\bf T}$ is the set $JtW({\bf 
        T})$ of  $\mathbb{C}^d$  such
        that
        $$JtW({\bf T})=\{(\langle T_1 x\; |\;x\rangle,\langle T_1 x\; 
        |\;x\rangle,\cdots,\langle T_d x
        |\;x\rangle)\;:x \in \mathcal{H},\;\;\|x\|=1\}.$$
    \end{mybox}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) I did not remember the `oversize` option so I stretched the box to right and then panned it to left. Your answer is more accurate and clean.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another workaround for this. You will need to add a couple of lines in `mybox` definition: `width=1.05\textwidth` and `left skip=-0.5cm` for the `tcolorbox` to keep the long equation and to center it in the frame.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} %math
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{color} %couleur

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
        width=1.05\textwidth,
        left skip=-0.5cm,
        colback=bg,
        colframe=blue!75!black,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        coltitle=blue!75!black,
        colbacktitle=bg,
        enhanced,
        attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-1.2mm, xshift=2mm},
        title=#2,
        #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\begin{mybox}[%
        colframe=blue!75!black,
        coltitle=black!75!black,
        colbacktitle=white!90!blue, 
        ] {\ding{43} Definition}

Let ${\bf T} = (T_1,\cdots, T_d)$ be $d$-tuple of operators in $\mathcal{B} (\mathcal{H}).$ The joint numerical range of ${\bf T}$ is the set $JtW({\bf T})$ of $\mathbb{C}^d$ such that

\[
JtW({\bf T})=\{(\langle T_1 x|x\rangle,\langle T_1 x|x\rangle,\cdots,\langle T_d x|x\rangle):x \in \mathcal{H},\|x\|=1\}.
\]

\end{mybox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```